# Pressing a key causes Triple Fault

Tags: c, x86, keyboard, osdev

As was said in the title, when I press a key, (thereby triggering IRQ 1, interrupt 33)
it causes a triple fault and resets.

I'm fairly sure this has something to do with the way I set up my IDT or how I initialize the PIC, so I'll give the code for both.

IDT.c:

```
#include "../drivers/IDT.h"
#include "../drivers/keyboard.h"
#include "../drivers/pci.c"

__attribute__((noreturn))
void execption_handler()
{
    __asm volatile ("cli; hlt"); // Hang and disable interrupts
}
__attribute__((noreturn))
void int_keyboard_handler()
{
    keyboard_handler(port_byte_in(0x60));
}

void load_idt_entry(uint8_t isr_number, unsigned long base, short int selector, uint8_t flags);
void load_idt_entry(uint8_t isr_number, unsigned long base, short int selector, uint8_t flags)
{
    idt_entry_t* descriptor = &idt[isr_number];
    descriptor->isr_low         = (uint32_t)base & 0xFFFF;
    descriptor->isr_high        = (uint32_t)(base >> 16) & 0xFFFF;
    descriptor->kernel_cs       = selector;
    descriptor->attributes      = flags;
    descriptor->reserved        = 0;
}

static void init_idt_pointer()
{
    idtr.limit = (sizeof(idt_entry_t) * IDT_SIZE) - 1;
    idtr.base = (unsigned int)&idt;
}

void load_idt()
{
    __asm volatile("lidt %0"::"m"(idtr)); // Load the new IDT
    
    __asm volatile ("sti"); // enable interrupts
}

extern void* isr_stub_table[];

void idt_init(void);
void idt_init()
{
    init_pic(0x20, 0x28);
    init_idt_pointer();
    for (uint8_t vector = 0; vector <= 33; vector++)
    {
        load_idt_entry(vector, (unsigned long)isr_stub_table[vector], 0x08, 0x08E);
    }
    load_idt();
}
```

IDT.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define IDT_SIZE 256

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t    isr_low;    // The lower 16 bits of the ISR's address
    uint16_t    kernel_cs;  // The GDT segment selector that the CPU will load into it's CS before calling the ISR
    uint8_t     reserved;   // Set to 0
    uint8_t     attributes; // Type and attributes
    uint16_t    isr_high;   // The higher 16 bits of the ISR's address
} __attribute__((__packed__)) idt_entry_t;

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t limit;
    uint32_t base;
} __attribute__((__packed__)) idtr_t;

__attribute__((aligned(0x10)))
static idt_entry_t idt[256];

static idtr_t idtr;
```

IDT.asm:

```
[extern _execption_handler]
[extern _keyboard_handler]

%macro isr_err_stub 1
isr_stub%+%1:
    pusha
    cld
    call _execption_handler
    popa
    cld
    iret
%endmacro
%macro isr_no_err_stub 1
isr_stub%+%1:
    pusha
    cld
    call _execption_handler
    popa
    cld
    iret
%endmacro

%macro keyboard_int 1
isr_stub%+%1:
    pusha
    cld
    call _keyboard_handler
    popa
    cld
    iret
%endmacro

isr_no_err_stub 0
isr_no_err_stub 1
isr_no_err_stub 2
isr_no_err_stub 3
isr_no_err_stub 4
isr_no_err_stub 5
isr_no_err_stub 6
isr_no_err_stub 7
isr_err_stub 8
isr_no_err_stub 9
isr_err_stub 10
isr_err_stub 11
isr_err_stub 12
isr_err_stub 13
isr_err_stub 14
isr_no_err_stub 15
isr_no_err_stub 16
isr_err_stub 17
isr_no_err_stub 18
isr_no_err_stub 19
isr_no_err_stub 20
isr_no_err_stub 21
isr_no_err_stub 22
isr_no_err_stub 23
isr_no_err_stub 24
isr_no_err_stub 25
isr_no_err_stub 26
isr_no_err_stub 27
isr_no_err_stub 28
isr_no_err_stub 29
isr_err_stub 30
isr_no_err_stub 31
keyboard_int 32


[global _isr_stub_table]
_isr_stub_table:
%assign i 0
%rep 33
    dd isr_stub%+i
%assign i i+1
%endrep
```

PIC.c

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define PIC1 0x20
#define PIC2 0xA0
#define PIC1_DATA 0x21
#define PIC2_DATA 0xA1

#define ICW1 0x11
#define ICW4 0x01

#define PIC_MASTER_CMD 0x20
#define PIC_MASTER_DATA 0x21
#define PIC_SLAVE_CMD 0xA0
#define PIC_SLAVE_DATA 0xA18

static void init_pic(int pic1, int pic2)
{
    // send ICW1
    port_byte_out(PIC1, ICW1);
    port_byte_out(PIC2, ICW1);
    
    // send ICW2
    port_byte_out(PIC1_DATA, pic1); /* remap */
    port_byte_out(PIC2_DATA, pic2); /*  pics */
    
    // send ICW3
    port_byte_out(PIC1_DATA, 4);    /* IRQ2 -> connection to slave */
    port_byte_out(PIC2_DATA, 2);

    // send ICW4
    port_byte_out(PIC1_DATA, 0x01);
    port_byte_out(PIC2_DATA, 0x01);
    
    // Mask interrupts
    port_byte_out(0x21, 0xFF);
    port_byte_out(0xA1, 0xFF);
}
```

keyboard.h

```
// Omitted `keyboard_map[]` as it's not relevant
unsigned char c;

unsigned char inputBuffer[16];

static int current_loc = 1;

void keyboard_init()
{
    unsigned char curmask_master = port_byte_in(0x21);
    port_byte_out(0x21, curmask_master & 0xFD);
}

void keyboard_handler()
{
    drawchar('!', current_loc++ * 8, 40, WHITE_ON_BLACK);
    signed char keycode;

    keycode = port_byte_in(0x60);

    if (keycode >= 0 && keyboard_map[keycode])
    {
        drawchar(keyboard_map[keycode], current_loc++ * 8, 40, WHITE_ON_BLACK);
    }
    //inputBuffer[0] = _c;

    // Send End Of Interrupt
    port_byte_out(0x20, 0x20);
}
```

kernel.c

```
#include "libs/IDT.c"

bool exit = false;

void start()
{
    idt_init();
    load_idt_entry(0x21, (unsigned long)isr_stub_table[0x21], 0x08, 0x8e);
    keyboard_init();

    while (true)
    {

    }
}
```

Sorry if this is considered too much code, but I can't think of a way to omit anything here as any part of this is where it could be going wrong.

The IDT structure (from Bochs debugger) is strange, the address where `keyboard_int` should be is labeled as `???`:

```
Interrupt Descriptor Table (base=0x0000000000000000, limit=65535):
IDT[0x00]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x01]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x02]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x03]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x04]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf087f000, length 0x0fea5
IDT[0x05]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf0e6f000, length 0x0e9e6
IDT[0x06]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf0e6f000, length 0x0e9e6
IDT[0x07]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf0e6f000, length 0x0ef57
IDT[0x08]=Code segment, base=0xf04dc000, limit=0x00000152, Execute-Only, Non-Conforming, 16-bit
IDT[0x09]=16-Bit TSS (Busy) at 0xf0fef000, length 0x0f841
IDT[0x0a]=Code segment, base=0xf059f000, limit=0x0000e739, Execute-Only, Non-Conforming, 16-bit
IDT[0x0b]=32-Bit Trap Gate target=0xf000:0xf000e82e, DPL=3
IDT[0x0c]=16-Bit Interrupt Gate target=0xf000:0xf0008f75, DPL=3
IDT[0x0d]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000fe6e, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x0e]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0xf000ff53
IDT[0x0f]=Data segment, base=0xc093f000, limit=0x0000efde, Read/Write, Accessed
IDT[0x10]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x11]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x12]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x13]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x14]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x15]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x16]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x17]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x18]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x19]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x1a]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x1b]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x1c]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x1d]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x1e]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x1f]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x20]=??? descriptor hi=0x9fc0003d, lo=0xf000ec59
IDT[0x21]=32-Bit Trap Gate target=0xf000:0xc000ff53, DPL=0
IDT[0x22]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x23]=Code segment, base=0xf0539fc0, limit=0x0000004d, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x24]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x25]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x26]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x27]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x28]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x29]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x2a]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x2b]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x2c]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x2d]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x2e]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x2f]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x30]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
IDT[0x31]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
IDT[0x32]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
IDT[0x33]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000 < here is where `keyboard_int` should be
IDT[0x34]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x35]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x36]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x37]=Code segment, base=0xf053f000, limit=0x0000ff53, Execute/Read, Conforming, Accessed, 16-bit
IDT[0x38]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf0ddf000, length 0x0fe93
IDT[0x39]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf0ecf000, length 0x0e9ec
IDT[0x3a]=LDT
IDT[0x3b]=32-Bit TSS (Available) at 0xf0ecf000, length 0x0933a
```

Comment: Can your simulator (e.g. Bochs) tell you which fault led to a double-fault as it tried to take int 0x33?  (and thus to a triple-fault if there was a bad double-fault handler?)  I think Bochs can at least dump the IDT and GDT, and page tables if paging is enabled, to help you verify that you put stuff where you intended.  You're not showing how you entered protected mode and so on; possibly that could be a problem?  (If you link your full code on github or similar, someone that wanted to play around with your full code could actually debug it that way without having to write a bootloader.)

Comment: Your inline asm for `lidt` looks right, and so does your packed struct for `lidt_t`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Here's my [Github repo](https://github.com/ThatCodingGuy86/UnnamedOS). And I'm using QEMU, I have no clue if it has that feature. No idea how to dump the IDT/GDT in Bochs though. And I've checked if I put the `keyboard_int` at the wrong address (in the IDT), nope, no matter what address I put it at, it just triple faults.

Comment: Bochs docs for its internal debugger: https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html

Comment: I've managed to get that to work, but I have _no idea_ what I'm doing in this GDB-like debugger. I've looked through the commands, but saw no way of directly dumping the IDT/GDT and have no idea how to dump the IDT/GDT using the commands

Comment: According to google, `info idt` should work.  (e.g. mentioned in https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=3a957f49-38e9-443d-a636-f5c2fb435e45).  But you're right, it's not mentioned in the debugger doc I linked :(.  Also, according to https://www.reddit.com/r/osdev/comments/8p12pj/how_to_debug_in_the_early_stages/, QEMU has a `-no_reboot` option to stop on a triple fault so you can examine things, in case Bochs doesn't already do that.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is normal:                                                                      
```IDT[0x30]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
IDT[0x31]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
IDT[0x32]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
IDT[0x33]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000``` The address where `keyboard_int` should be is just ???. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Doesn't look normal; probably should edit your question with that info.  If you can get Bochs to show you the current IDTR, that might help.  (Or maybe set a breakpoint on your `lidt` instruction, you could double-check what virtual address is getting set at that point.  Or physical if you haven't enabled paging.  But you tagged this [x86-64], and you can only enter long mode if paging is enabled.)

Comment: I meant to tag it as just x86, oops. I'm in Protected Mode here. Also, you might want to look at my IDT structure (I updated the question) to check if more stuff is off, because I can't tell.

Comment: Perhaps the segment selector in that entry is invalid?  Do you have paging enabled?  If so, maybe the offset part is in an unmapped page?  I see you do have some valid-looking IDT entries, so the lidt itself probably was ok.  Maybe try dumping the memory yourself for that IDT entry and check the fields manually against https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table#Structure_on_IA-32 since it's not clear from Bochs's summary info exactly what's wrong with it, just that it's somehow bogus.

Comment: No, I don't have paging enabled. By segment selector, do you mean the thing I named `kernel_cs` in the `idt_entry_t` struct? If so, is it supposed to be the code segment? (my GDT is flat if that matters)

Comment: It seems your double-fault IDT entry (0x08) isn't fully valid, so that's probably why you get a triple fault any time you get a double fault.  I guess that's fine if you don't actually intend to catch double-faults other than with a debugger.

Comment: What do you mean by not fully valid? In what way is it invalid? (Also, read my previous reply)

Comment: Yeah, the segment selector is bits 16..31 (the 2nd word) of the IDT entry.  And yeah, `kernel_cs` would be the normal thing to have there.  selector:offset get loaded into CS:EIP when an interrupt is taken.  The low 2 bits of it are a privilege level, the rest of the bits are an index into the GDT or LDT, depending on the 3rd bit, IIRC.

Comment: Bochs says your double-fault descriptor is "Non-Conforming, 16-bit".  That sounds problematic.

Comment: I wonder why? Some of the same code (in IDT.asm) is producing completely different results, somehow

Comment: Actually it's saying all your IDT entries are 16-bit, if they're valid at all.   Did you forget to set the "gate type" bitfield?  I assume it should be 32-bit interrupt gate (0b1110 = 0xe).  https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table#Structure_on_IA-32

Comment: If you look at line 67 of IDT.c, it's definitely set to 0x8E.

Comment: Yeah, I see that in the source, and the `idt_entry_t` looks defined correctly.  Probably a good idea to check a hexdump with the debugger, to make sure it actually has that value in memory at run-time.  (And maybe check the GDT to make sure GDT[1] is a 32-bit code segment, in case that's what Bochs is reporting.)

Comment: GDT: ```Global Descriptor Table (base=0x0000000000007cca, limit=23):
GDT[0x0000]=??? descriptor hi=0x00000000, lo=0x00000000
GDT[0x0008]=Code segment, base=0x00000000, limit=0xffffffff, Execute/Read, Non-Conforming, Accessed, 32-bit
GDT[0x0010]=Data segment, base=0x00000000, limit=0xffffffff, Read/Write, Accessed``` I can't figure out how to do a memory dump...

Comment: According to the manual https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html you should be able to `x  <addr>` , with format options maybe somewhat like GDB's x command.  Apparently there's also a debugger GUI which might make it even easier to look at memory.

Comment: I just found something really strange. When my program gets to the loop at the end of `kernel.c`, all the memory for the IDT gives me this error: ```bx_dbg_read_linear: physical memory read error (phy=0x000060100000, lin=0x0000000060100000)
error: IDTR+8*0 points to invalid linear address 0x0000000060100000``` (goes on for every entry)

Comment: I tried using `x <addr>`, but it gave me the same error as my previous reply. Really odd.

Comment: Probably you overwrote (part of) your page tables.  Bochs's `xp` can dump physical memory, vs. `x` dumping linear.

Comment: _What_ page tables?

Comment: Oh right, you said you didn't enable paging.  Well that's odd.  Maybe check your segment registers, see if somehow the segment limits or bases got messed up.  Or is there somehow a jump to linear address `0x60100000` somewhere?  That's 1537 MiB; does your simulated machine have that much?  That might be why it's an invalid physical address.  Hmm, maybe if CS base got set high somehow, that could explain trying to access such a high linear address.

Comment: `does your simulated machine have that much?` I'm not sure. How do I check?

Comment: With Bochs info commands, like `sreg` like it says in the manual, https://bochs.sourceforge.io/doc/docbook/user/internal-debugger.html

Comment: I forgot I specified a memory amount in the settings. It says it's at 32, I'm going to see what happens when I set it to 1700 MB

Comment: Now instead of a valid IDT, it looks like I'm getting _no_ IDT. _What on Earth is going on!?_

Comment: Presumably then your wrong pointer will point at "valid" memory, but still not the memory you want to point at.  (e.g. some zeroed memory near the top of phys RAM).  Check your segment regs, and check CS:EIP, at that point.  Maybe an interrupt handler is returning with the wrong CS:EIP and/or messing up DS?  (Remember that IDT is accessed via an *offset* in DS, not a linear or physical address.)

Comment: Oh. That makes sense. The GDT says the base is at 0. That's not right, it's supposed to be at 0x1000. Segment registers:  https://pastebin.com/pGJe7V1z I'm not sure what you mean by CS:EIP

Comment: * or DS (wouldn't let me edit)

Comment: Seriously, you don't know what segment registers are?  CS and DS are segment registers, like in your pastebin dump.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation.  A flat memory model *should* have base=0, limit=-1 like you have. Likely your `0x1000` is actually an offset relative to 0 (the DS base), not what you want the DS base to be. CS:EIP is standard notation for EIP as an offset in the CS segment, where the CPU fetches code from.  If you don't want to deal with that x86 legacy baggage, maybe play around with a different architecture, like ARM or RISC-V, for your toy OS.

Comment: Ohh I completely forgot that's what the segment registers were called. I also for some reason thought base was the _offset_ from the base, I remember how this works now. I also completely forgot that EIP is the notation for instruction pointer.. Honestly, I actually like having to solve these problems of programming in x86 (although it can be very frustrating at times), so I'm probably going to stick with x86 unless I have a good reason to use a different architecture (e.g some feature is impossible to do in x86 and is possible to do in some other architecture)

Comment: Anyways, I'm going to see if I can see if DS or CS:EIP is broken after returning from `keyboard_int` (if it even gets to return before double, then triple faulting)